# How does allocateIds() work in Cloud Datastore Mode?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, python-3.7

In the new Datastore Mode documentation, there is [mention of `allocateIds()` method](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#assigning_your_own_numeric_id). However, beyond a single paragraph, there isn't an example code that illustrates how this method is used.

I am trying to allocate an ID each time I create a new entity so that I can save the ID as a property of the entity itself.

I assume that in pseudocode, it works like this:

```py
    user_id = allocateIds(number_id_ids=1)
    user_key = datastore_client.key(kind='User', user_id)
    user = datastore.Entity(key=user_key)
    user.update({ 'user_id': user_id })  # Allows a get_user_by_id() query
    datastore_client.put(user)
```

How exactly does `allocateIds()` work in practice?

Comment: `allocateIds()` is useful when you want to reserve a bunch of entity IDs at once. If you only need one ID at a time, you can build keys like in [these examples](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#assigning_identifiers). Does that make sense?

Comment: @JuanLara, what if you want to know the id of the entity to be created before it is created? There is the option to manually make up your own id, but it seems more secure to allow datastore to generate one for you. EDIT: Sorry, I have edited the question with more details.

Comment: Yes, it's good to use automatic IDs. Note that you can make the `allocateIds(number_ids=1)` implicit when you ask for a key. Will add a snippet soon.

Comment: Re-reading your question, your approach works if you need to store a `user_id` property that's the same as the entity ID. However, you might not need to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `allocateIds()` should work for the case where you want to get an ID from Datastore mode and use it as both an ID and property value:

```
from google.cloud import datastore

client = datastore.Client()

# Allocate a single ID in kind User
# Returns list of keys
keys = client.allocate_ids(client.key('User'), 1)

# Get key from list
key = keys[0]
print(key.id)

# Create a User entity using our key
user = datastore.Entity(key)

# Add ID as a field
user.update({
    'user_id': key.id
})

# Commit to database
client.put(user)

# Query based on full key

query = client.query(kind='User')
query.key_filter(user.key, '=')

results = list(query.fetch())
print(results)
```

For most other cases where you just want a single auto-ID, you can skip `allocate_ids`:

```
# Create a User entity
# Use an incomplete key so Datastore assigns an ID
user = datastore.Entity(client.key('User'))

# Add some data
user.update({
    'foo': 'bar'
})

# Datastore allocates an ID when you call client.put
client.put(user)

# user.key now contains an ID
user_id = user.key.id
print(user_id)

# Query with the ID and key

query = client.query(kind='User')
query.key_filter(user.key, '=')

results = list(query.fetch())
print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this scenario, the the put(user) is called and then the user_id is extracted from `user.key.id`. However, to save the user_id property within user, we would need to call put() twice. Won't the allocateIds() method solve this problem by allocating the user_id before hand so that we can call 
`user.update({ id:allocated_id, 'foo': 'bar' })`?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. My suggestion is that you might not need to store the ID twice (in the entity ID and as a property).

Comment: That's a good suggestion for 99% of the situations. However, in my particular situation, I am using a Flask-Login extension that requires a `user_id` property to create sessions. Otherwise, I would take the recommended approach. Any idea on how allocateIds() can be used here instead?

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for clarifying. Updated the answer with an example of `allocate_ids`.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the `allocateIds()` function it invokes a new instance of `class Key(object)` when the consturctor of "Key" is called it takes all of the arguments you provided `allocateIds` and recombines them through a `_combine_args` method. That is what produces your key.

(and if you want to see the code yourself)

source: https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/_modules/google/cloud/datastore/key.html#Key

Comment: thanks for the link. Would you mind including a coded example of how it is used?

Comment: @puoygae [Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/ndb/entities/snippets.py#L156) you can find some code examples of the allocate_ids() method

Comment: @JoseV, it looks like this example uses the previous ndb datastore. I am looking for examples for the new 'Datastore Mode' datastore.